# Web scraping sorted tables

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull data of the website below. I have managed to get the data I require, but the person who wants this done wants the option to access the different tabs.

For example, data can be sorted by 7 days, this month, 3 months and 6 months. How do I switch between these tabs?

Thanks a bunch everyone! :D

https://www.overbuff.com/heroes

Answer (score 0):

The site is dynamic and thus loads new data via a script when each tag is selected. Thus, you will need to use a browser manipulation tool such as `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import collections
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
def get_hero_data(s):
  names = [a for i, [_, a] in enumerate(re.findall('/heroes/(.*?)">(.*?)</a>', s)) if i%2 != 0]
  numbers = re.findall("<span>(.*?)%</span>", s)
  final_numbers = [[re.findall('[\d\.]+$', a)[0], b, c, d] for a, b, c, d in [numbers[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(numbers), 4)]]
  return [[a]+b for a, b in zip(names, final_numbers)]

hero_listing = {}
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/driver')
driver.get('https://www.overbuff.com/heroes')
hero_listing['this month'] = get_hero_data(driver.page_source)
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('filter-option')
for i, t in enumerate([buttons[0], buttons[2], buttons[3]]):
   t.click()
   hero_listing[['this week', 'last 3 months', 'last 6 months'][i]] = get_hero_data(driver.page_source)
```

Output:

```
{'this week': [[u'Moira', u'10.44', u'51.39', u'2.42', u'8.64'], [u'D.Va', u'9.31', u'52.42', u'2.35', u'10.08'], [u'Mercy', u'7.61', u'50.47', u'2.61', u'2.14'], [u'Reinhardt', u'6.58', u'51.46', u'2.70', u'9.04'], [u'Roadhog', u'5.41', u'49.64', u'2.08', u'9.30'], [u'Genji', u'5.35', u'50.35', u'2.02', u'11.80'], [u'Zenyatta', u'5.34', u'53.25', u'2.20', u'8.57'], [u'Ana', u'4.91', u'46.90', u'2.28', u'10.39'], [u'Junkrat', u'4.45', u'51.21', u'2.76', u'12.08'], [u'L\xfacio', u'4.42', u'51.22', u'1.94', u'10.23'], [u'McCree', u'4.20', u'48.23', u'1.85', u'11.62'], [u'Tracer', u'4.03', u'49.23', u'1.93', u'9.51'], [u'Winston', u'3.95', u'48.58', u'2.13', u'6.46'], [u'Soldier: 76', u'3.91', u'49.95', u'2.31', u'10.84'], [u'Zarya', u'3.23', u'47.79', u'2.29', u'10.99'], [u'Orisa', u'2.93', u'52.61', u'2.64', u'10.85'], [u'Pharah', u'2.90', u'50.23', u'2.09', u'12.99'], [u'Widowmaker', u'2.57', u'48.16', u'2.09', u'9.63'], [u'Reaper', u'2.38', u'49.77', u'2.11', u'16.33'], [u'Hanzo', u'1.98', u'45.91', u'2.16', u'13.63'], [u'Symmetra', u'0.83', u'59.44', u'4.07', u'7.53'], [u'Doomfist', u'0.81', u'48.29', u'1.68', u'7.37'], [u'Torbj\xf6rn', u'0.68', u'55.48', u'4.27', u'13.65'], [u'Mei', u'0.64', u'47.47', u'2.46', u'8.15'], [u'Bastion', u'0.62', u'48.59', u'2.70', u'16.44'], [u'Sombra', u'0.53', u'45.10', u'2.31', u'13.26']], 'this month': [[u'Moira', u'9.89', u'51.47', u'2.45', u'8.96'], [u'D.Va', u'9.35', u'52.51', u'2.40', u'10.47'], [u'Mercy', u'8.31', u'50.48', u'2.63', u'2.45'], [u'Reinhardt', u'6.15', u'51.35', u'2.74', u'9.19'], [u'Zenyatta', u'5.63', u'53.29', u'2.25', u'9.01'], [u'Roadhog', u'5.62', u'49.72', u'2.06', u'9.72'], [u'Genji', u'5.19', u'50.51', u'2.06', u'12.26'], [u'Ana', u'4.87', u'46.59', u'2.35', u'10.88'], [u'Junkrat', u'4.59', u'51.40', u'2.81', u'12.78'], [u'McCree', u'4.29', u'48.36', u'1.91', u'12.01'], [u'L\xfacio', u'4.10', u'51.36', u'1.93', u'10.66'], [u'Winston', u'4.02', u'48.74', u'2.12', u'6.84'], [u'Soldier: 76', u'3.90', u'50.10', u'2.35', u'11.36'], [u'Tracer', u'3.87', u'49.34', u'1.97', u'9.87'], [u'Orisa', u'3.28', u'53.01', u'2.64', u'11.41'], [u'Zarya', u'3.19', u'47.80', u'2.37', u'11.40'], [u'Pharah', u'2.96', u'50.26', u'2.11', u'13.26'], [u'Widowmaker', u'2.55', u'48.45', u'2.10', u'10.02'], [u'Reaper', u'2.36', u'49.80', u'2.07', u'16.86'], [u'Hanzo', u'1.91', u'46.05', u'2.21', u'14.13'], [u'Symmetra', u'0.83', u'59.90', u'4.19', u'7.71'], [u'Doomfist', u'0.75', u'48.44', u'1.79', u'7.41'], [u'Torbj\xf6rn', u'0.67', u'55.84', u'4.42', u'14.49'], [u'Bastion', u'0.61', u'49.17', u'2.61', u'17.19'], [u'Mei', u'0.59', u'48.34', u'2.41', u'8.57'], [u'Sombra', u'0.51', u'45.56', u'2.34', u'13.73']], 'last 6 months': [[u'Mercy', u'11.71', u'51.99', u'2.63', u'3.08'], [u'D.Va', u'8.66', u'52.70', u'2.38', u'11.22'], [u'Moira', u'8.49', u'51.01', u'2.43', u'8.82'], [u'Reinhardt', u'6.44', u'51.46', u'2.74', u'9.61'], [u'Roadhog', u'5.39', u'50.04', u'2.01', u'10.88'], [u'Zenyatta', u'4.89', u'53.11', u'2.25', u'9.91'], [u'Junkrat', u'4.86', u'52.13', u'2.77', u'15.09'], [u'Genji', u'4.82', u'50.30', u'2.05', u'13.40'], [u'Ana', u'4.46', u'45.60', u'2.34', u'11.57'], [u'McCree', u'4.35', u'48.64', u'1.92', u'13.52'], [u'Soldier: 76', u'4.34', u'50.23', u'2.35', u'12.68'], [u'Winston', u'3.96', u'48.88', u'2.07', u'7.26'], [u'Zarya', u'3.73', u'48.18', u'2.37', u'12.09'], [u'Tracer', u'3.59', u'49.10', u'1.93', u'10.90'], [u'L\xfacio', u'3.38', u'50.80', u'1.83', u'10.59'], [u'Pharah', u'3.15', u'50.86', u'2.08', u'14.57'], [u'Orisa', u'3.04', u'53.14', u'2.66', u'12.36'], [u'Widowmaker', u'2.41', u'48.51', u'2.10', u'11.12'], [u'Reaper', u'2.36', u'50.10', u'1.99', u'18.23'], [u'Hanzo', u'1.99', u'46.14', u'2.21', u'15.63'], [u'Symmetra', u'0.86', u'60.06', u'4.24', u'7.85'], [u'Doomfist', u'0.72', u'48.43', u'1.77', u'8.44'], [u'Torbj\xf6rn', u'0.68', u'55.74', u'4.42', u'15.23'], [u'Bastion', u'0.65', u'50.14', u'2.58', u'18.92'], [u'Mei', u'0.57', u'48.57', u'2.43', u'9.33'], [u'Sombra', u'0.50', u'45.14', u'2.36', u'14.04']], 'last 3 months': [[u'Mercy', u'11.71', u'51.99', u'2.63', u'3.08'], [u'D.Va', u'8.66', u'52.70', u'2.38', u'11.22'], [u'Moira', u'8.49', u'51.01', u'2.43', u'8.82'], [u'Reinhardt', u'6.44', u'51.46', u'2.74', u'9.61'], [u'Roadhog', u'5.39', u'50.04', u'2.01', u'10.88'], [u'Zenyatta', u'4.89', u'53.11', u'2.25', u'9.91'], [u'Junkrat', u'4.86', u'52.13', u'2.77', u'15.09'], [u'Genji', u'4.82', u'50.30', u'2.05', u'13.40'], [u'Ana', u'4.46', u'45.60', u'2.34', u'11.57'], [u'McCree', u'4.35', u'48.64', u'1.92', u'13.52'], [u'Soldier: 76', u'4.34', u'50.23', u'2.35', u'12.68'], [u'Winston', u'3.96', u'48.88', u'2.07', u'7.26'], [u'Zarya', u'3.73', u'48.18', u'2.37', u'12.09'], [u'Tracer', u'3.59', u'49.10', u'1.93', u'10.90'], [u'L\xfacio', u'3.38', u'50.80', u'1.83', u'10.59'], [u'Pharah', u'3.15', u'50.86', u'2.08', u'14.57'], [u'Orisa', u'3.04', u'53.14', u'2.66', u'12.36'], [u'Widowmaker', u'2.41', u'48.51', u'2.10', u'11.12'], [u'Reaper', u'2.36', u'50.10', u'1.99', u'18.23'], [u'Hanzo', u'1.99', u'46.14', u'2.21', u'15.63'], [u'Symmetra', u'0.86', u'60.06', u'4.24', u'7.85'], [u'Doomfist', u'0.72', u'48.43', u'1.77', u'8.44'], [u'Torbj\xf6rn', u'0.68', u'55.74', u'4.42', u'15.23'], [u'Bastion', u'0.65', u'50.14', u'2.58', u'18.92'], [u'Mei', u'0.57', u'48.57', u'2.43', u'9.33'], [u'Sombra', u'0.50', u'45.14', u'2.36', u'14.04']]}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it was really helpful. Do you know of a way this can be done without opening a browser though?

Comment: @KieranMontgomery: apologies; however, I do not think that is possible given the current site you are using. The website uses javascript to access the data from the backend to display. Therefore, there has to be some medium to trigger the execution of the script. However, you could find other sites that also post the data for player rankings that would be even easier to scrape as well.

Comment: @Ajax1234, actually a request is sent to this link: `https://www.overbuff.com/tank/heroes?v=49a568b&time=1w&platform=1&game_mode=2&group_hero=true` in which you can change `time=1w` to 1m, 3m, or 6m as per required. But I don't really understand the response (it's not JSON). It's some long string. If possible, please take a look at the response in the developer tools.